# how to load css and js files dynamically according to component in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular14

I have html dashboard template, where each page content their own css and js;
i want that, each component comes with thier css and js.

I am Django developer and new in Angular.

please help me.

Comment: that's the default behavior of Angular? Then I still not really understand your problem

Comment: Any angular component comes with a scss(better version of CSS) file and ts (JS with types) file. You can write your css and js logic in those files.